# How to get all the nodes which are coming after a particular tag using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, xpath, nokogiri

I want to fetch all the HTML tags which are coming after the particular tag. For example:

```html
<html>
    <body>
       <p>one</p>
       <u><p>Two</p></u>
       <b><p>Three</p></b>
       <p>Four</p>
       <table>
          <tr><td>Five</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Six</td></tr>
       </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want all the HTML tags which are coming after `<u><p>Two</p></u>` using Nokogiri.

My result should be:

```html
<b><p>Three</p></b>
<p>Four</p>
<table>
   <tr><td>Five</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Six</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `<u><p>Two</p></u>` is invalid HTML, Nokogiri will change it to `<u></u><p>Two</p>` when parsing as HTML (similarly for `<b><p>Three</p></b>`.

Answer (score 2):

The [`following-sibling` XPath axis](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes) is what you want here. Your example isn’t valid HTML, and Nokogiri will change it when parsing as HTML making it hard to demonstrate using it, but with this similar code:

```html
<html>
    <body>
       <p>one</p>
       <p>Two</p>
       <p>Three</p>
       <p>Four</p>
       <table>
          <tr><td>Five</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Six</td></tr>
       </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

this XPath expression:

```
//p[.="Two"]/following-sibling::*
```

will select this:

```html
<p>Three</p>
<p>Four</p>
<table>
          <tr><td>Five</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Six</td></tr>
       </table>
```

You might want to use `node()` instead of `*`, which will select all text nodes as well as elements (including whitespace only nodes):

```
<p>Three</p>
<p>Four</p>
<table>
  <tr><td>Five</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Six</td></tr>
</table>
```

(There will be some more leading whitespace on each line if you do this, I‘ve removed it here.)